# Как извлечь из базы 10 последних записей, а не первых попавшихся?

Tags: php, mysql

Рандомное извлечение не подходит. Записей может быть тысячи. Необходимо, что-бы извлекались последние.

Comment: а структура базы какая? как нам узнать какие там записи последние? Вообще для этого делают `ORDER BY field DESC`

Comment: "Вы что же, и есть за меня будете?"

Comment: Автор даже не уточнил ему код на PHP или запрос к MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table-name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

при условии, что id - primary key с автоинкрементом, иначе подставить сюда релевантную колонку из вашей таблицы, created_at или что там еще может указывать на порядок добавлений

Comment: А если `id` нет? Наверное по `table_field` корректнее

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, я уже тоже подумал, что надо как-то уточнить

Answer (score 2):

В реляционной алгебре и в языке SQL считается, что множества это неупорядоченный набор значений. Сталобыть нет такого понятия как "последние 10 записей" без **явного** указания сортировки. Вот добавите `ORDER BY`, тогда порядок будет. Без него любые предположения могут оказаться ошибочными!

В случае автоинкрементного ключа, "последними" можно считать строки с наибольшими id. Опять с оговоркой: если им не явно не присваивались значения — это не запрещено.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию выводятся данные, которые были добавлены последними, но при этом все же стоит указать `ORDER BY id` и, конечно же, `LIMIT 10`, и пора уже знать такие элементарные ключевые слова как ASC и DESC.

Comment: *по умолчанию выводятся данные которые были добавлены последними* - разве? а может которые были обновлены последними? или может в порядке первичного ключа? скажу одно - смотрел как-то запрос в консоли mysql и в php-скрипте к той же базе. Запрос один и тот же, что-то типа `select * from table limit 10` - результаты были разными. Что-то из них возвращало словно по Id сортировало, что-то - вроде как то, что было изменено последним. Поэтому "по умолчанию" не совсем корректно говорить, к тому же - в разных БД такое поведение может отличаться

Comment: Не исключено...

Comment: кстати, про "умолчания", если есть запрос вида `SELECT... GROUP BY name`, то mysql автоматически сортирует по `name`, поэтому на эти "умолчания" лучше не надеяться, а явно указывать что вы хотите. Для того же `group by` сортировка иногда очень вредна, поэтому может помочь `ORDER BY NULL` - и никакой сортировки не будет

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю зачем это, но наиболее быстрый результат даст автоинкрементное поле.
Но если очень надо извратится, пронумеруйте строки,  и выберите первые десять с конца, например так:

```
SELECT @i := @i + 1 as no , ad_gen.*
FROM ad_gen,  (select @i:=0) a
order by no desc limit 10
```